# boost factory with different products' return value

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost, factory

I use boost factory to create products, what I want to do is to call different products for its `DoSomething()`, but the problem is that I want that every product's return value is different, and all of them are structs. I want ProductA->DoSomething(), then its return value will be structA, for ProductB->DoSomething(), its return value will be strucB. And all of structures drive from base `struct`, is it possible? Thanks for your solution, really appreciate!

Comment: is it possible for dynamic_cast in boost::share_ptr ? Thanks

Comment: Sure use boost::dynamic_pointer_cast

Comment: @DenisErmolin if I want to use the return value to call its own method, how to use `boost::dynamic_pointer_cast `, productA's DoSomething() will return structA, but I can't use structA's members which don't derive from ReturnStruct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare base `struct ReturnType` which will define base methods and variables. Then you can create products without any problem for you.

```
struct ReturnType
{
    virtual std::string getName(){}
};
struct MarsType : ReturnType 
{
    std::string specialMethod()
    {
        return "MARS";
    }
};
struct SnikersType : ReturnType 
{
    std::string specialMethod2()
    {
        return "SNIKERS";
    }
};

class Product
{
    public:
        virtual ReturnType* doSomething()=0;
};

class SnikersProduct : public Product
{
public:
    ReturnType* doSomething()
    {
        return static_cast<ReturnType*>(&value);
    }
private:
    SnikersType value;
};

class MarsProduct : public Product
{
public:
    ReturnType* doSomething()
    {
        return static_cast<ReturnType*>(&value);
    }
private:
    MarsType value;
};

class Creator
{
public:
    virtual Product* createProduct()=0;
};


class SnikersCreator : public Creator
{
public:
    Product* createProduct()
    {
        return new SnikersProduct();
    }
};

class MarsCreator : public Creator
{
public:
    Product* createProduct()
    {
        return new MarsProduct();
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Creator*> creators;
    creators.push_back(new MarsCreator());
    creators.push_back(new SnikersCreator());
    Product* mars = creators[0]->createProduct();
    Product* snikers = creators[1]->createProduct();
    std::cout<<"mars product returns "<<dynamic_cast<MarsType*>(mars->doSomething())->specialMethod()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"snikers product returns "<<dynamic_cast<SnikersType*>(mars->doSomething())->specialMethod2()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is :

```
mars product returns MARS
snikers product returns SNIKERS
```

Comment: yeah, it is good, but when the return value is a sniker, it can't call its special method, which doesn't derive from the base class.

Comment: Edited answer, then use dynamic_cast, but better change your design a bit

Comment: I tried, but running with errors for .exe. I will modified my code to let you see, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

No problem at all thanks to return type covariance. This is a C++ feature and means that a virtual function implemented in a derived class can return a pointer (or reference) to the same class as the function implemented (or declared, if pure virtual) in the base class **or a pointer (or reference) to a class derived from that**. This means that your code is correct C++.

You say that your code compiles correctly, as it should because of return type covariance, as explained in the previous paragraph. You also say that you get errors at runtime, but I'm afraid we cannot help you with that unless you specify what are those errors you are getting.